# Retrying tcpClient connection with a delay

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcpclient

I have a tcp server and client that are started at about the same time, but the server may not yet be up by the time the client attempts to connect to it. The client should not fail at this point, but after some delay retry the connection up to some limit. The solution below works, but placing a Thread.Sleep the exception handler like this, on a thread I have no control over, seems wrong. Is there a better way to do this?

This is in an older version of .Net so the async keyword and Task class are not available to me.

```
// Starts the client
public void Start(
    int connectRetryAttempts,
    int connectRetryDelay)
{
    this.connectRetryAttempts = connectRetryAttempts;
    this.connectRetryDelay = connectRetryDelay;

    tcpClient.BeginConnect(EndPoint.Address, EndPoint.Port, ConnectCallback, null);
    State = States.Connecting;
}

// Handles BeginConnect completion
private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    try
    {
        tcpClient.EndConnect(asyncResult);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (connectRetryAttempts > 0)
        {
            --connectRetryAttempts;
            Thread.Sleep(connectRetryDelay * 1000);
            tcpClient.BeginConnect(EndPoint.Address, EndPoint.Port, ConnectCallback, null);
        }
        else
        {
            State = States.Disconnected;
            Log.LogErrorFormat("Exception encountered trying to connect: {0}", ex);
        }
        return;
    }

    State = States.Connected;
    buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    networkStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, ReadCallback, null);
}
```

Comment: Definitely use a `System.Threading.Timer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)

```
if (connectRetryAttempts > 0)
{
    --connectRetryAttempts;
    Timer delay = null;
    delay = new Timer(_=> 
    {
       tcpClient.BeginConnect(EndPoint.Address, EndPoint.Port, ConnectCallback, null);
       delay.Dispose();
    }, connectRetryDelay * 1000, Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

With the interval set to `Timeout.Infinite` the timer will fire only one time.

Comment: Ah, I mistakenly thought Timer was only introduced along with async and Task. I see it is available in 3 as well!